# Countdown is still counting after 0

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have a small problem i'm using this code to start counting from 20 too 0:

```
 mainInt = 20;
        randomMain = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(randomMainVoid)
                                                    userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

but after 0 the countdown is still counting ( -1, -2,-3)

```
-(void) randomMainVoid {

    mainInt -=1;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%D", mainInt];


}
```

Does anyone know how to stop counting after 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you still have a pointer to your NSTimer, you want to call the [- invalidate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/invalidate) method.

```
if (mainInt <= 0)
{
    [randomMain invalidate];
    [randomMain release]; // remove if you're using ARC.
}
```

Comment: It would be safer to check if mainInt is `<=` rather than `==`

Answer (score 0):

Send `invalidate` to timer in `randomMainVoid` and release it when reaching 0.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking in most coding languages I have used as others have, in the loop that counts down a if statement, that when 0 is reached, you reset the count, or stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Once your finished using the timer object (in your case once your iVar reaches 0) you'll have to call the invalidate method on your timer object.

```
[randomMain invalidate];
```